# How to properly set value of editable div?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For input and other elements with value I could use `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(input, 'value').set;` and then `element.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', {bubbles: true}))`, but this doesn't work for contentEditable div. There is no value to set and no set() function in it.

I'm trying to simulate sending message in Twitch chat, I need it for my chrome extension. I know it's stupid to do it via UI, but this is only way I know. If you can manually type in chat, then there gotta be some way to do it programmatically, right? If you go to twitch and try method above on search field, it will work, because it's normal input. How to do same thing on chat?

Comment: if it is a div maybe you can change its innerText/innerHTML.
You should track the javascript stack when sending a message and see how Twitch receives your message and what events are triggered.

Comment: how to do it? Chrome debug tool is too complicated

Answer (score 0):

The input field for the Twitch chat is actually a `<textarea>` that also has a `value` attribute that you can set programmatically with:

```
let textarea = document.querySelector("textarea");
textarea.value = "foobar";
```

However you might need to tweak this a little when there are more than just one textarea on the page.

Comment: is it textarea for you now? That's weird because for me it's not anymore. It was before, but they changed it and that's why my extension doesn't work anymore.

Comment: It is, yes. What does `document.querySelectorAll("textarea")` return for you?

Comment: empty nodelist array. Chat for me is an div element with contenteditable="true" property. Mb they changed it not for everyone yet somehow?

Answer (score 0):

you could simply do this in a Stream Chat:

```
document.querySelector('textarea').innerText = "hello world";
document.querySelectorAll('.Layout-sc-nxg1ff-0.dWdTjI')[5].click();
```

Comment: this way you don't actually change the state and it won't work